# How to migrate data from one data bucket to another bucket in couchbase using C#?

Tags: c#, nosql, couchbase

I have a data bucket named "SourceBucket".. I have few views and documents in that.. I need to migrate all those completely to another bucket named " DestinationBucket".. I m using c#.. Is this possible..

The problem for me is getting the documents and views from sourcebucket.. How can i get that..
 Kindly help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing specific in the C# Couchbase client performing a migration.  If you're using Couchbase Server 2.0, you could use a view and perform inserts into the second bucket as you loop over the view.  Another approach might be to use the backup and restore (outside of C#).

http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-1.8/couchbase-backup-restore.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple tool to use that comes packaged with Couchbase, cbtransfer.

You can use this tool to transmit contents from one bucket to another, in your case, just create the new bucket where you would like to transfer to end up, and using cbtransfer will get the data and the views there.

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/docs-ng/blob/master/content/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-cli/cbtransfer_tool.markdown

As a side, if you only need to transfer the views, use cbtransfer with the -x design_doc_only=1 switch.